# Print from parent to child c

Tags: c, fork

I am trying to make an **E-shop** in which the child is a bot client. I have a struct with 2 items and the client will randomly pick 0 or 1 which is an item. At the parent. I want to check if the item is in stock If not, I want to return to the child the `catalog[].description` and print it there. My question is I have to write again `if(pid==0){ (make the print here) }` or I have to go to the very first `pid==0` and write it there?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>

struct items
{
    char *description;
    double price;
    int item_count;
};

int main()
{

    struct items catalog[2];
    catalog[0].item_count = 2;
    catalog[0].description = "psigio";
    catalog[0].price = 10;
    catalog[1].item_count = 2;
    catalog[1].description = "thleorash";
    catalog[1].price = 20;

    int pf[2], pf2[2], ran, random, i;
    char ofs[30] = "";

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        if (pipe(pf) == -1)
        {
            perror("Pipe");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (pipe(pf2) == -1)
        {
            perror("Pipe 2");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            ran = rand() % 2;
            close(pf[0]);
            write(pf[1], &ran, sizeof(int));
            printf("Child random: %d\n", ran);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        if (pid > 0)
        {
            wait(NULL);
            close(pf[1]);
            read(pf[0], &random, sizeof(int));
            close(pf[0]);
            printf("Parent random: %d\n", random);
            printf("Item: %s\n", catalog[random].description);
            if (catalog[random].item_count > 0)
            {
                catalog[random].item_count--;
                printf("Stock is: %d\n", catalog[random].item_count);
            }
            else
            {
                close(pf2[0]);
                write(pf2[1], catalog[random].description, strlen(catalog[random].description) + 1);
            }
        }
        sleep(1);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, your question is unclear: What you need to do depends on what you want to achieve. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I want to check the stock in the parent, if the stock is zero i want to return to the child the item description which is in the catalog[].description threw a pipe and print in the child that this item is out of stock

Comment: Well, why don't you do that then? You don't even describe a problem, only some work that needs to be done.

Comment: As i wrote, i asked where i must write this part of code. Should i write it in the first pid==0 or underneath the else i have to write again pid==0. I tried both of them obv but nothing worked. So if i know where i have to write it i can understand what i am doing wrong. Pipes and forks are new to me. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Really, please read [ask]. Nobody here knows what you mean with "nothing worked"!